# How to fix mysql django connection on mac OS?. I already installed mysqlclient but "Did you install mysqlclient?" Error displayed

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-connection

I am setting a new *Django 2.2* project with *MySQL 8.0* on mac. I already installed mysqlclient and mysql-connector-python. When I hit `python manage.py makemigrations` this displayed:

```
"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module. Did you install mysqlclient?"
```

I am using python 3.7.
How can I solve this problem?

I already installed `pip install mysqlclient mysql-connector-python`

Will not work for Python 3.7

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: did you use `brew install mysql-connector-c`? also mysqlclient, is it in correct virtual environment(same as the project)? :)

Comment: Would you mind checking your installed packages (in your environment) with `pip freeze`?

Comment: @ruddra I installed and linked with brew link. I am in the same environment.

Comment: did you unlink mysql-connector-c and linked mysql? BTW, maybe this link will help: https://ruddra.com/posts/install-mysqlclient-macos/

Comment: I tried @ruddra but not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysqlclient globally and in your project. I think you should install once globally on your pc and try

Comment: Install mysqllidev which help to make the development server of mysql